# Swift SpriteKit Hearts not appending in last spot

Tags: arrays, swift, sprite-kit

Im working on a SpriteKit game and the player starts with three hearts, when he gets hit he loses one and if he collects a heart item he can get a heart back. I got it all to work but when he gets a heart back they appear around the last heart.

```
// 1: here is the function for when he loses a heart

func takeDamage() {
        if invulnerable || damaged { return }
        lives -= 1
        
        let lastElementIndex = heartsArray.count - 1
        print(heartsArray.count)
        if heartsArray.indices.contains(lastElementIndex - 1) {
            let lastHeart = heartsArray[lastElementIndex]
            lastHeart.removeFromParent()
            print("removed heart")
            heartsArray.remove(at: lastElementIndex)
        }

// 2: here is the original filling of hearts

func fillHearts(count: Int) {
           for index in 1...count {
               let heartTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "heart")
               let heart = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "heart")
               heart.size = CGSize(width: heartTexture.size().width / 4, height: heartTexture.size().height / 4)
               let xPosition = heart.size.width * CGFloat(index - 1)
               heart.position = CGPoint(x: xPosition, y: 0)
               heartsArray.append(heart)
               heartContainer.addChild(heart)
               
               
           }

// 3: and here is the adding + 1 heart when he gets a heart item


if refillHeart == true {
            for index in 0..<1 {
                   let heartTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "heart")
                   let heart = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "heart")
                   heart.size = CGSize(width: heartTexture.size().width / 4, height: heartTexture.size().height / 4)
                   let xPosition = heart.size.width * CGFloat(index - 1)
                   heart.position = CGPoint(x: xPosition, y: 0)
                   heartsArray.append(heart)
                   heartContainer.addChild(heart)
                print(heartsArray)
                   refillHeart = false
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because in your `for` loop, the `index` is always 0, so the `xPosition` will always be 0.

```
if refillHeart == true 
{
    let heartTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "heart")
    let heart = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "heart")
    heart.size = CGSize(width: heartTexture.size().width / 4, height: heartTexture.size().height / 4)

    // this was the problem
    // let xPosition = heart.size.width * CGFloat(index - 1) 
    // because of your for loop, the index was always 0 


    // get number of displayed hearts
    let heartsNumber: CGFloat = CGFloat(heartsArray.count)
    let xPosition = heart.size.width * heartsNumber

    heart.position = CGPoint(x: xPosition, y: 0)
    heartsArray.append(heart)
    heartContainer.addChild(heart)
    print(heartsArray)
    refillHeart = false
}
```